# initial state of LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I would like to inspect the internal state of an LSTM layer.
In particular I would like to look at the status at prediction time, after feeding a new example to the network.

I have understood this can be done using:

```
from keras import backend as K
# load pre-trained model somewhere
# select a LSTM layer
for layer in model.layers:
    if 'LSTM' in str(layer):
       break
# get inputs somewhere

val = np.random.random((...))
x = K.variable(value=val)

initial_state = layer.get_initial_states(???)
[desired_states]=layer.step(inputs=x,states=initial_state)
```

What is the input shape required by `get_initial_states`?
Is this a correct way of inspecting an LSTM